# Need list of URLs of sites accessing my files

Tags: php

I have a file on my site and many external sites are importing this file on their websites with the `file_get_contents` php code.

Is it somehow possible with PHP to get the URL of these external sites accessing my file? Something like: if siteX accesses my page Y, add siteX URL to sites.txt

Comment: You can get the IP of the webserver, you can't get the name of the page. You may be able to use reverse DNS to translate the IP to a hostname, but if they're using shared hosting that won't tell you the specific name of the server that's accessing your file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to your server: simply parse the `access.log`.

If you don't have access to the server, then you might try to determine the Client IP via `$_SERVER`.

`$visitors_ip = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REMOTE_ADDR');`

More here: [How to get the client IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)

Boils down to: on each request, determine visitor ip and store to your file.

Comment: How manage the request in PHP if the external site do a `file_get_content()` to a file ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible, unless all the sites are yours. You can't know what is in other people's PHP code.

You might track the IP addresses, probably, but it'll be tedious and unreliable task.

Are you sure this is really what you want? Wouldn't it be better to use some kind of redirection instead?

Comment: I don't want to know what is in other people's php code. I just want to know which sites are accessing my website. I thought there was a simple way.

Comment: Well there isn't, simple as that. If it was hypertext links (`<a>`), you could try to find it in Google Webmaster Tools, but if it is via direct request or `file_get_content()`, there is no such option. You can use IP, but it won't always work, and also you'll have hard time finding what website it was.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can log the referral header from Apache for every request, if you can configure apache on your site.

Here you can find an example of how to achieve this:

http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/logging-external-referers-with-apache/